# find out the intersection between a straight line and a curve parametrized by phi on a complex plane

Tags: complex-numbers, curves, intersection-theory

The equation for a straight line is simply:
$$
y = mx + c
$$
Let's say for now that the other curve is a unit circle $z = e^{i\phi}$, we know that:
$$
y^2 + x^2 = 1
$$
which can simply be solved by substitution. Now consider the following:
$$
f(z, \phi) = a(\phi)z^2 + bz + c = 0
$$
where the coefficient $a(\phi) = e^{i\phi}$, b and c are complex constants. There are 2 solutions for the polynomial root $z$:
$$
z = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}
$$
which is implicitly a function of $\phi$ and should form a closed loop like how a circle would. My question is that, for a curve like this, I do not have a definition like the equation of a circle, so how should I go about solving the intersection between such a curve and a straight line?

Comment: When you say $z = ar^2 + br + c$ you are implicitly saying that $z$ is parametrically dependent on $(r,\phi)$. When you say $r = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$ you are explicitly saying that $z=0$. What exactly are you trying to find? I thought you want to find the intersection of a straight line with a curve in the plane.

Comment: $z = ar^2+br+c$ is NOT the curve that I am looking at, but solving $z = 0$ to obtain the polynomial root r which is dependent on $\phi$ forms the curve that I am looking at. I have edited my post for clarification, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Okay, my misunderstanding. In that case, you do get two closed curves in the plane that are sort of circular but are not centered at the origin. You would have to look for intersections with the straight line independently.

Comment: yes but the question is how do I obtain an expression for the intersection, if such expression exists in an analytical manner?

Comment: Well, given the nature of the functions $r$, I think it's highly unlikely that analytical solutions will be forthcoming. I have some experience in looking for overlap of closed figures, but it's numerically tedious. Perhaps a first step you could take is to find the circumcenter of the function $r$ and see if the circle intersects the line. However, the first thing that I would do is to plot everything up and see what it looks like. That's what I did with your problem. I used arbitrary (random) values of $b$ and $c$. There's a wide range in the nature of the results.

Comment: I was hoping to look for an analytical expression but I suppose there probably isn't one. In fact the polynomial that I am currently working with is even more complicated - a quartic polynomial, with all of the coefficients somewhat related to $e^{i\phi}$.